# Find Adjacent Nodes A Star Path-Finding C++

Tags: c++, path-finding, a-star

Is there a better way to handle my FindAdjacent() function for my A Star algorithm? It's awfully messy, and it doesn't set the parent node correctly. When it tries to find the path, it loops infinitely because the parent of the node has a pent of the node and the parents are always each other.

Any help would be amazing. This is my function:

```
void AStarImpl::FindAdjacent(Node* pNode)
{
    for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++)
        {
            if (pNode->mX != Map::GetInstance()->mMap[pNode->mX + i][pNode->mY + j].mX 
                || pNode->mY != Map::GetInstance()->mMap[pNode->mX + i][pNode->mY + j].mY)
            {
                if (pNode->mX + i <= 14 && pNode->mY + j <= 14)
                {
                    if (pNode->mX + i >= 0 && pNode->mY + j >= 0)
                    {
                        if (Map::GetInstance()->mMap[pNode->mX + i][pNode->mY + j].mTypeID != NODE_TYPE_SOLID)
                        {
                            if (find(mOpenList.begin(), mOpenList.end(), &Map::GetInstance()->mMap[pNode->mX + i][pNode->mY + j]) == mOpenList.end())
                            {

                                Map::GetInstance()->mMap[pNode->mX+i][pNode->mY+j].mParent = &Map::GetInstance()->mMap[pNode->mX][pNode->mY];
                                mOpenList.push_back(&Map::GetInstance()->mMap[pNode->mX+i][pNode->mY+j]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    mClosedList.push_back(&Map::GetInstance()->mMap[pNode->mX][pNode->mY]);
}
```

If you'd like any more code, just ask and I can post it.

Comment: It would certainly be more readable if you stored `Map::GetInstance()->mMap[pNode->mX + i][pNode->mY + j]` in a local `Node` instance in the loop! It would be very handy if you could provide a simple, self-contained and compilable example of your code exhibiting a failure mode.

Comment: typically, the graph that A* operates on doesn't need to be directed. That is, A* doesn't care if your nodes have parents. So the algorithm shouldn't fail because two nodes are parents of one another; in fact, A* should never look at the `.parent` member at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce the amount of nested ifs by using `continue`. Generally speaking, the following two code blocks are equivalent:

```
while(conditionA){
    if(conditionB){
        doStuff();
    }
}

while(conditionA){
    if (!conditionB){continue;}
    doStuff();
}
```

We can use this principle to reduce the amount of nested ifs in your code.

```
void AStarImpl::FindAdjacent(Node* pNode)
{
    for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++)
        {
            if (pNode->mX == Map::GetInstance()->mMap[pNode->mX + i][pNode->mY + j].mX && pNode->mY == Map::GetInstance()->mMap[pNode->mX + i][pNode->mY + j].mY){continue;}
            if (pNode->mX + i > 14 || pNode->mY + j > 14){continue;}
            if (pNode->mX + i < 0 || pNode->mY + j < 0){continue;}
            if (Map::GetInstance()->mMap[pNode->mX + i][pNode->mY + j].mTypeID == NODE_TYPE_SOLID){continue;}
            if (find(mOpenList.begin(), mOpenList.end(), &Map::GetInstance()->mMap[pNode->mX + i][pNode->mY + j]) != mOpenList.end()){continue;}
            Map::GetInstance()->mMap[pNode->mX+i][pNode->mY+j].mParent = &Map::GetInstance()->mMap[pNode->mX][pNode->mY];
            mOpenList.push_back(&Map::GetInstance()->mMap[pNode->mX+i][pNode->mY+j]);
        }
    }

    mClosedList.push_back(&Map::GetInstance()->mMap[pNode->mX][pNode->mY]);
}
```

If I understand your first `if` condition correctly, you're just trying to assert that pNode is not its own neighbor. In which case you can change the code to:

```
void AStarImpl::FindAdjacent(Node* pNode)
{
    for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0 && j == 0){continue;}
            if (pNode->mX + i > 14 || pNode->mY + j > 14){continue;}
            if (pNode->mX + i < 0 || pNode->mY + j < 0){continue;}
            if (Map::GetInstance()->mMap[pNode->mX + i][pNode->mY + j].mTypeID == NODE_TYPE_SOLID){continue;}
            if (find(mOpenList.begin(), mOpenList.end(), &Map::GetInstance()->mMap[pNode->mX + i][pNode->mY + j]) != mOpenList.end()){continue;}
            Map::GetInstance()->mMap[pNode->mX+i][pNode->mY+j].mParent = &Map::GetInstance()->mMap[pNode->mX][pNode->mY];
            mOpenList.push_back(&Map::GetInstance()->mMap[pNode->mX+i][pNode->mY+j]);
        }
    }

    mClosedList.push_back(&Map::GetInstance()->mMap[pNode->mX][pNode->mY]);
}
```

Ideally, your FindAdjacent method should not have to modify the open or closed sets at all. instead, make it return all neighbors, regardless of whether they are open or closed. If you want to add these neighbors to the opened or closed set, or check that they are a member of those sets, that should be done in the method that actually implements the aStar algorithm.

```
Vector<Node> AStarImpl:FindAdjacent(Node* pNode)
{
    Vector<Node> neighbors;
    for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0 && j == 0){continue;}
            if (pNode->mX + i > 14 || pNode->mY + j > 14){continue;}
            if (pNode->mX + i < 0 || pNode->mY + j < 0){continue;}
            if (Map::GetInstance()->mMap[pNode->mX + i][pNode->mY + j].mTypeID == NODE_TYPE_SOLID){continue;}
            neighbors.push_back(Map::GetInstance()->mMap[pNode->mX+i][pNode->mY+j]);
        }
    }
    return neighbors;
}
```

You perform some of the same operations multiple times. You can make your intentions more clear by storing the results of those operations in variables. Doing this won't make your code any shorter, but it might make it more readable.

```
Vector<Node> AStarImpl:FindAdjacent(Node* pNode)
{
    Vector<Node> neighbors;
    for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0 && j == 0){continue;}
            int x = pNode->mX + i;
            int y = pNode->mY + j;
            if (x > 14 || y > 14){continue;}
            if (x < 0 || y < 0){continue;}
            Node candidate = Map::GetInstance()->mMap[x][y];
            if (candidate.mTypeID == NODE_TYPE_SOLID){continue;}
            neighbors.push_back(candidate);
        }
    }
    return neighbors;
}
```

Comment: Wow. I have only just started using StackOverflow, but if anybody else is as helpful as you, I'm sticking around. Thank you so much for taking the time to give me such in depth help. I seriously appreciate it. I was half expecting to be told how much of an awful programmer I am if I'm honest. So genuinely, I'm very grateful.